# No output from opencv in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, opencv3.0

I am new to OpenCV. This code runs on my Visual Studio 2017 but does not display any result even after entering the command line argument. The program runs fine and builds successfully without error or build failure notification. I have tried several times but there has not been a solution to this problem. Please can someone help out?

```
 #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    Mat src, erosion_dst, dilation_dst;
    int erosion_elem = 0;
    int erosion_size = 0;
    int dilation_elem = 0;
    int dilation_size = 0;
    int const max_elem = 2;
    int const max_kernel_size = 21;
    void Erosion(int, void*);
    void Dilation(int, void*);
    int main(int, char** argv)
    {
        src = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);
        if (src.empty())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        namedWindow("Erosion Demo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        namedWindow("Dilation Demo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        moveWindow("Dilation Demo", src.cols, 0);
        createTrackbar("Element:\n 0: Rect \n 1: Cross \n 2: Ellipse", "Erosion Demo",
            &erosion_elem, max_elem,
            Erosion);
        createTrackbar("Kernel size:\n 2n +1", "Erosion Demo",
            &erosion_size, max_kernel_size,
            Erosion);
        createTrackbar("Element:\n 0: Rect \n 1: Cross \n 2: Ellipse", "Dilation Demo",
            &dilation_elem, max_elem,
            Dilation);
        createTrackbar("Kernel size:\n 2n +1", "Dilation Demo",
            &dilation_size, max_kernel_size,
            Dilation);
        Erosion(0, 0);
        Dilation(0, 0);
        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
    void Erosion(int, void*)
    {
        int erosion_type = 0;
        if (erosion_elem == 0) { erosion_type = MORPH_RECT; }
        else if (erosion_elem == 1) { erosion_type = MORPH_CROSS; }
        else if (erosion_elem == 2) { erosion_type = MORPH_ELLIPSE; }
        Mat element = getStructuringElement(erosion_type,
            Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1),
            Point(erosion_size, erosion_size));
        erode(src, erosion_dst, element);
        imshow("Erosion Demo", erosion_dst);
    }
    void Dilation(int, void*)
    {
        int dilation_type = 0;
        if (dilation_elem == 0) { dilation_type = MORPH_RECT; }
        else if (dilation_elem == 1) { dilation_type = MORPH_CROSS; }
        else if (dilation_elem == 2) { dilation_type = MORPH_ELLIPSE; }
        Mat element = getStructuringElement(dilation_type,
            Size(2 * dilation_size + 1, 2 * dilation_size + 1),
            Point(dilation_size, dilation_size));
        dilate(src, dilation_dst, element);
        imshow("Dilation Demo", dilation_dst);
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that you have the file in the wrong place. before `return -1;` you should print an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have maybe a problem with the arguments...

try replacing `src = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR);` with

```
src = imread("myPathTo/lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
```

I've tried with lena and is working fine by me:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That worked for me. Please do you know the reason the command line argument is not working?                         C:/Users/God's Property/Desktop/lena.jpg

Comment: Did you quote that? The space in the path will turn that into 2 command line arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That worked for me. Please do you know the reason the src = imread("C:/Users/God's Property/Desktop/lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR); works  but C:\Users\God's Property\Desktop\lena.jpg will not work?

Comment: @drescherjm  I didn't quote that in the command line. I entered it like that @ ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ Now I know. Thank you so much for your help